Display Published Posts Count for Time Period
The actual question is how to create a counter for new posts for a certain time (per hour or per day) on a Wordpress blog. So that you can place it in the site menu. Thank you very much in advance :)
I found this code, as I understand it, it needs to be placed in the functions.php file, but I don’t understand how to add displays of the counter itself to the menu.
$posts= get_posts(array(
                'numberposts' => -1,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order'   => 'DESC',
                'date_query'    => array(
                    'column'  => 'post_date',
                    'after'   => '-7 days'  // -7 Means last 7 days 
                )
            ));

When I add this code to the menu it always shows 0:
<h3>Post Count: <?php echo count($posts); ?></h3>

Tell me how to fix this?
